# HTML PDF embedding blocks controls in html modal

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, rendering, embed

I'm using `<embed src="<%= path %>" type="application/pdf" />` to preview pdf file on the page. It works great until I open my custom modal window with position fixed  covering pdf preview area. Modal window has buttons and I cannot click on any. It seems modal is covered by something invisible. I tried to play around with z-indexes but it didn't work out. Embedding with tag `<object data="" type="application/pdf"></object>` caused the same problem - I cannot click on the button.

The main problem of the issue is that it can be reproduced at particular computers in spite of the same Chrome version (version: 69.0.3497.100 64-bits) Did anyone face such pdf rendering issues in Chrome?

Here is the link to test this issue https://fatuk.github.io/test-pdf-render

Comment: The embed and object tags rely on the native PDF viewer, either OS level or browser level. You have no control over the PDF experience when you display the PDF using these tags. Use something like PDF.js instead. PDF.js will let you control every aspect of how the PDF is displayed in the browser. It's not a perfect solution in that it can't display all types of PDF but it is a *predictable* experience.

Comment: @joelgeraci I investigated Chrome PDF viewer and it's implemented on Polymer. But it's really really blackbox. It seems my issue is just Chrome bug. Anyway thanks for the answer .